# Firestore can sometimes write data, other times not. Set Data will not enter callback

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to write data in cloud firestore. I have taken the sample code from the firestore documentation on adding data to the dabase, which is:

```
 db = Firestore.firestore()
 db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData([
            "name": "Los Angeles",
            "state": "CA",
            "country": "USA"
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error writing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully written!")
            }
        }
```

This did not work at first, then worked one time, and has not worked since. I change the title of the document from "LA" to something different every time so that a new document would be added. Why might Firestore add the data sometimes and not others? When it does not add the data, it does not enter the callback function either.

I have searched other questions on stack overflow for setData() not entering the callback function, but there are not answers that explain the one-time connectivity.

Comment: That code will work every time. So that means the issue lies elsewhere; perhaps in how Firebase is being init'ed, authentication or a number of other variables. You should add a breakpoint in your code and step through your *other* code line be line until something doesn't give you expected results.

Comment: Thank you very much. Writing data in that case is now working every time, but I cannot read data. I get the error: "Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds. This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend." I know my internet connection is sufficient because I just wrote data to firestore and I can see it in the firestore console. Why is the connection not working in this case?

Comment: Again, the issue will lie elsewhere. You may have an infinite loop, or something interfering with the connection or a poor download connection stream or... or... or. We won't be able to help without seeing the problematic code. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)